# TypeScript-ifying old JavaScript 'Element implicitly has an any'

Tags: typescript

I was wondering why I get this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.

I understand that the `acc` hasn't been declared. The values and types have been defined previously. What's the right way to approach this using TypeScript?

```
// mediaQueries.ts
const min = (width: number) => `only screen and (min-width: ${width}em)`
const max = (width: number) => `only screen and (max-width: ${width}em)`

// The screen widths in em units.
export const screens = {
  phone: 30,
  phablet: 40,
  tablet: 50,
  netbook: 60,
  laptop: 70,
  desktop: 100,
}

export const mediaQueries = Object.entries( screens ).reduce(
  ( acc, [key, val] ) => {
    const Key = key[0].toUpperCase() + key.substr( 1 )
    // css query
    acc[`min` + Key] = `@media ` + min( val ) // <- Error Here
    acc[`max` + Key] = `@media ` + max( val ) // <- Error Here
    // js query (see window.matchMedia)
    acc[`min` + Key + `Js`] = min( val ) // <- Error Here
    acc[`max` + Key + `Js`] = max( val ) // <- Error Here
    return acc
  }, {}
)
```

Comment: The simplest would be `{ [key: string]: string }`, you could maybe do something interesting with the new [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) given you have a fixed key structure. Also note that it's weird to use backticks without interpolation then _concatenate_ other strings, especially given that e.g. `min` shows how to actually use template strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array#reduce` can take a type argument:

```
[].reduce<Record<string, string>>((acc, [key, val]) => { ... }, {});
```

---

#### Update (14-4-2021)

Another way is to annotate the iteratee function:

```
[].reduce((acc: Record<string, string>, [key, val]) => { ... }, {});
```

then compiler will infer the type from the iteratee.